# Filling under histogram until exact point with fill_between python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, fill, percentile

Currently, I am trying to fill under the histogram with fill_between function in python until 10 and 90 percentile in the original numbers.
However, the problem is the histogram curve is not a "function' but the series of discrete number with the interval of bin size. I couldn't fill exactly up to 10 or 90 percentile. I have tried several tries, I failed.
The code bellow is what I tried:

```
S1 = [0.34804491  0.18036933  0.41111951  0.31947523 .........

0.46212255  0.39229157  0.28937502  0.22095423  0.52415083]
N, bins = np.histogram(S1, bins=np.linspace(0.1,0.7,20), normed=False)
bincenters   = 0.5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])    
ax.fill_between(bincenters,N,0,where=bincenters<=np.percentile(S1,10),interpolate=True,facecolor='r', alpha=0.5)
ax.fill_between(bincenters,N,0,where=bincenters>=np.percentile(S1,90),interpolate=True, facecolor='r', alpha=0.5,label = "Summer 10 P")
```

It seems to fill only until bincenter before or after given percentile number, not until up to those.

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.
Isaac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your last two lines to:

```
ax.fill_between(bincenters, 0, N, interpolate=True,
                where=((bincenters>=np.percentile(bincenters, 10)) &
                       (bincenters<=np.percentile(bincenters, 90))))
```

I believe you want to call `np.percentile` on `bincenters` since that is your effective x-axis.

The other difference is that you want to want fill between regions where `10<x<90`, which necessitates the use of `&` in the `where` parameter.

**Edit based on comment from OP:**

I think to achieve what you want, you have to do some minimal interpolation of your own. See my example below using a random, normal distribution in which I'm using `interp1d` from `scipy.interpolate` to interpolate over `bincenters`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# create normally distributed random data
n = 10000
data = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
bins = np.linspace(-data.max(), data.max(), 20)
hist = np.histogram(data, bins=bins)[0]
bincenters = 0.5 * (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])

# create interpolation function and dense x-axis to interpolate over
f = interp1d(bincenters, hist, kind='cubic')
x = np.linspace(bincenters.min(), bincenters.max(), n)

plt.plot(bincenters, hist, '-o')
# calculate greatest bincenter < 10th percentile
bincenter_under10thPerc = bincenters[bincenters < np.percentile(bincenters, 10)].max()
bincenter_10thPerc = np.percentile(bincenters, 10)

bincenter_90thPerc = np.percentile(bincenters, 90)
# calculate smallest bincenter > 90th percentile
bincenter_above90thPerc = bincenters[bincenters > np.percentile(bincenters, 90)].min()

# fill between 10th percentile region using dense x-axis array, x
plt.fill_between(x, 0, f(x), interpolate=True,
                 where=((x>=bincenter_under10thPerc) &
                        (x<=bincenter_10thPerc)))

# fill between 90th percentile region using dense x-axis array, x
plt.fill_between(x, 0, f(x), interpolate=True,
                 where=((x>=bincenter_90thPerc) &
                        (x<=bincenter_above90thPerc)))
```

The figure I get out is below. Note that I changed the percentiles from 10/90% to 30/70% so that they show up better in the plot. Again, I hope that this is what you're trying to do

[image: plt.fill_between within percentiles]

Comment: @Ianery: I appreciate your answer. However, I am not trying to fill the region between 10 <x<90. I tried to fill between 10 and the largest bin center smaller than 10 and between 90 and the smallest bin center larger than 90.

Comment: @Isaac I edited my answer to include what it is that I think you're trying to do.

Comment: @Ianery. Thank you very much. You seem to make a function with interpolation. It really helps. Isaac

Answer (score 0):

I have a version of this that uses `axvspan` to make a Rectangle and then uses the hist as a clip_path:

```
def hist(sample, low=None, high=None):
    # draw the histogram
    options = dict(alpha=0.5, color='C0')
    xs, ys, patches = plt.hist(sample,
                               density=True,
                               histtype='step', 
                               linewidth=3,
                               **options)

    # fill in the histogram, if desired
    if low is not None:
        x1 = low
        if high is not None:
            x2 = high
        else:
            x2 = np.max(sample)

        fill = plt.axvspan(x1, x2, 
                           clip_path=patches[0],
                           **options)
```

Would something like that work for you?